# Where is the clipboard stored in an iOS backup?

Tags: ios, ipad, backup, copy-paste, data-recovery

I have a recent backup of my iPad.

**Where can I find the clipboard in the backup ?**

I know that the clipboard is kept between restarts. So I think — and hope — that it is stored somewhere in backups.

Comment: I don't know for certain, but I'd very much doubt something as ephemeral as the clipboard would be saved in a backup. Simple test would be to do a restore then paste; see if anything's there.

Comment: @Tetsujin - I have restored an iPad from a backup, and then, to my great surprise, the clipboard was full! So it means that the clipboard of the backup did get restored... or that (more strangely) the restore did leave the existing clipboard intact.

Comment: I guess the only way to tell would be to backup, change the clipboard, then restore.

Answer (score 1):

And there are backup viewers, like [iphonebackupviewer](http://www.imactools.com/iphonebackupviewer/)
(haven't used) ...google for same, download trials and see what you like. But I don't see clipboard mentioned, and haven't seen it when I've viewed backups in the past.

Comment: On my Mac, I have iExplorer, which is quite nice.